# Image with some overlaid text

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, environments

I am looking for a possibility to do notes in a picture.

Like this examples of [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz)

But: If I change `width=1.0\textwidth` the positions of the nodes should stay the same like here:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{mwe}% for the example image
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.62,0.65) rectangle (0.78,0.75);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And: I like this way of definition and the corresponsing output

```
 \annotatedFigureBox{0.084,0.614}{0.394,0.804}{A}{0.084,0.614}%


\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{images/example.jpg}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.62,0.65) rectangle (0.78,0.75);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I merge the last two examples so that I

1. can change `width=1.0\textwidth` and the positions of the nodes will
   stay the same and
2. I have the possibility to define notes like this:     `\annotatedFigureBox{0.084,0.614}{0.394,0.804}{A}{0.084,0.614}%`

Is there an other way to reach my target?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What exactly do you want to merge?

Comment: In standalone, \textwidth is either undefined or set to 0pt.  Try putting the image into a minipage first.

Answer (score 6):

As I understand the question it is asking for a command that displays an image with some overlaid text on top of it. The command should provide an easy way to set the image size, as a ratio of `\textwidth`, and the position of the overlay.

The code below defines a such a macro: `\annotatedImage`. For example,

```
 \annotatedImage{example-image}{Hello}
```

produces:

[image]

The `\annotatedImage` command has one optional argument that accepts the following key-value pairs:

- `width=w`: this sets the width of the image as a ratio of the `textwidth`. By default, the width of the image will be `\textwidth`, corresponding to `width=1`
- `x=?` and/or `y=?`: Sets the `x` and `y` coordinates for the overlaid text. Both `x` and `y` are given ratios of the *displayed* image width and height, respectively, and they are measured from the `south west` corner. The default position of the overlaid text is `x=0.7,y=0.7`.
- In addition, arbitrary tikz node style specifications can be given, which will be applied to the node that contains the overlaid text.

For example, the commands:

```
\annotatedImage[width=0.5, x=0.5, y=0.5, blue, fill=white]{example-image}{Hello}
\annotatedImage[width=0.5, y=0.2, draw=red, circle]{example-image}{Hello}
```

produce:

[image]

**Edit**

In the comments the OP asked if it is possible to add more than one annotation to an image. Expanding the syntax of the `\annotatedImage` command would make this too contrived I think, especially because if we can add two annotations then the next question is likely to be if can add three annotations, or arrows or ducks etc etc. So, instead, I think that it is better to create an environment that is essentially a `tizpicture` environment in disguise. This environment should contain the image and be scaled so that picture occupies the (typically non-square) rectangle with  vertices `(0,0)--(1,0)--(1,1)--(0,1)`. Given this, arbitrary `tikz` commands can then be used to decorate the image using coordinates that are scaled relative to the picture. For example, the commands

```
\begin{AnnotatedImage}[width=0.5, draw=blue]{example-image}
  \annotate (H) at (0.7,0.7){Hello};
  \annotate[fill=white,draw=red] (B) at (0.7,0.2){Hello};
  \draw[blue, thick,->](H) -- (B);
\end{AnnotatedImage}
```

produce the following:

[image]

Similar to  the `\annotatedImage` command, the `AnnotatedImage` environment has two arguments:

- An optional argument for setting the width of the image as a fraction of `\textwidth` (as before, the default is `1`). In addition, style options can be given for the nodes constructed with `\annotate` for the overlaid image text.
- The name of the image file

The `AnnotatedImage` environment does *not* add any annotations for you and, instead, you have to do this "by hand". To help with this there is a "helper" command `\annotate`, which is nothing more than a shorthand for `\node[annotatedImage]`, using the same `annotatedImage` tikz style as above. The `\annotate` command should be used in exactly the same way as the `tikz` node commands. In particular, `\annotate` has an optional argument that is added to the style for the node. In the example above,

```
\annotate[fill=white,draw=blue] (B) at (0.7,0.2){Hello};
```

is the same as

```
\node[annotatedImage,fill=white,draw=blue] (B) at (0.7,0.2){Hello};
```

Here is the updated code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{mwe}% for the example image

\tikzset{% styling for the overlay
  annotatedImage/x/.initial = 0.7,% default overlay position
  annotatedImage/y/.initial = 0.7,
  annotatedImage/width/.initial = 1,% default image width
  annotatedImage/.unknown/.code = {% unknown keys are appended to style
    % to append to a style we need to expand everything first
    \edef\tikzappend{\noexpand\tikzset{annotatedImage/.append style =
                {\pgfkeyscurrentname=\pgfkeyscurrentvalue}}}
    \tikzappend
  },
  annotatedImage/.style = {% default overlay style
    draw=red, ultra thick, rounded corners, rectangle,
  }
}

\newsavebox\annotatedImageBox% need to calculate the width and height

% internal helper functions
\newcommand\AnnotatedImageVal[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/annotatedImage/#1}}
\newcommand\SetUpAnnotatedImage[2]{% set keys and dimensions to scale image
    \tikzset{annotatedImage/.cd, #1}%
    \sbox\annotatedImageBox{\includegraphics[width=\AnnotatedImageVal{width}\textwidth,
                                          keepaspectratio]{#2}}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\annotatedHeight{\ht\annotatedImageBox/28.453}% convert from px to a tikz length
    \pgfmathsetmacro\annotatedWidth{\wd\annotatedImageBox/28.453}%
}

% usage: \annotatedImage[node options]{image}{text}
\NewDocumentCommand\annotatedImage{ O{} m m}{%
  \bgroup% start a group to keep tikz changes local
    \SetUpAnnotatedImage{#1}{#2}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=\annotatedWidth, yscale=\annotatedHeight]%
        \node[inner sep=0, anchor=south west] (image) at (0,0) {\usebox{\annotatedImageBox}};
        \node[annotatedImage] at (\AnnotatedImageVal{x},\AnnotatedImageVal{y}) {#3};
    \end{tikzpicture}%y
  \egroup%
}

% usage: \annotate <insert favourite node commands>;
\newcommand\annotate[1][]{\node[annotatedImage,#1]}

% usage: \begin{AnnotatedImage][width(default 1)]{image} tikz commands....\end{AnnotatedImage}
\newenvironment{AnnotatedImage}[2][1]{%
  \SetUpAnnotatedImage{#1}{#2}%
  \tikzpicture[xscale=\annotatedWidth, yscale=\annotatedHeight]
    \node[inner sep=0, anchor=south west] at (0,0) {\usebox{\annotatedImageBox}};
}{\endtikzpicture}


\begin{document}

\annotatedImage{example-image}{Hello}

\bigskip

\annotatedImage[width=0.5, x=0.5, y=0.5, blue, fill=white]{example-image}{Hello}
\annotatedImage[width=0.5, y=0.2, draw=red, circle]{example-image}{Hello}

\newpage

  \begin{AnnotatedImage}[width=0.5]{example-image}
    \annotate (H) at (0.7,0.7){Hello};
    \annotate[fill=white,draw=blue] (B) at (0.7,0.2){Hello};
    \draw[blue, thick,->](H) -- (B);
  \end{AnnotatedImage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do more than one overlayed text in the same image?

Comment: @user146872 After writing this I learned of the [callouts](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/callouts) package. It does something similar, and I think it allows for this, so you might want to look at it. Adding multiple overlay texts is certainly possible but doing this would change the "design" of my macro quite a lot so it is quite a bit of additional work. Since you didn't mention this in the original question I think that if you want this then you should ask a new question.

Comment: I know callouts, but nobody else (can help) ... https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398586/different-notes-in-callouts

Comment: And callouts dose not work with  0  ... 100 or 0 .. 1 for the position, it works with a raster.

Comment: OK, I thought about this a little more and have now added the `AnnotatedImage` environment to address your comment. This environment is essentially a `tikzpicture` environment in disguise, so it allows you to add arbitrary`tikz` code over the top of the image. In particular, you can add as many overlaid pieces of text as you like. Inside `AnnotatedImage`, the `tikzpicture` environment is scaled so that the image fits into the (non-square) unit box.

Comment: @user146872 I am not sure how or why you have lost the ability to make comments... I am confused my your question below, however, because my code says that you use `\annotate` exactly as if it is a tikz `\node` command. Is your problem that "rounded reetangle" should be "rounded corners, rectangle"? In fact, `\annotate[fill=blue,text width=2cm,align=center,font=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white}] (B) at (0.7,0.2){Hello};` is enough because `rounded corners, rectangle` is part of the default.

Comment: @user146872 You should accept this answer. You cannot expect an answer to do absolutely everything for you: the Ti*K*Z manual has excellent tutorials and you should look at those to learn about the full range of possibilities for configuration.