# Putting tikzpicture within overpic

Tags: tikz-pgf, overpic

I want to "annotate" a pdf with arrows and stuff drawn in tikz, but I don't understand how to put tikz `draw` commands inside the overpic `put` command.

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikx}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}

\begin{document}
\begin{overpic}{filename_of_orig_pdf}

\put(0,0){Can easily put text}

\put(x,y){ \draw[] {}; }     %?

\end{overpic}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you keep drawing on the TikZ picture?

Comment: Here's an alternative: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171483/mathematical-formulas-on-a-graph-not-made-by-tex

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398584/image-with-some-overlaid-text and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz