# Include and edit a pdf in LaTeX-Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pdf

I want to include an excerpt of a pdf-document in my Beamer-presentation. Furthermore, I want to highlight a part of this document, i.e. draw a red rectangle around it, maybe even have an arrow point towards it.

I only have the free version of Adobe Acrobat Reader, so I don't even know how to do this without LaTeX. Except, of course, I can take a screenshot of the excerpt and then edit it using PowerPoint:

Is there a nice way to do this in Beamer ?

[image]

Comment: You can use `\includegraphics[page=..., crop=...]{<your pdf file>}` to select page and fragment inside a `tikz` node and add marks as is explained in [Drawing on an image in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little while ago I wrote some [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398584/image-with-some-overlaid-text) for annotating images that works equally well for annotating PDF files inside beamer. My macros define an `AnnotatedImage` environment where the coordinates are scaled so that the rectangular image fits inside a suitably scaled unit square, which makes it pretty easy to draw on the image. For example, you can produce the following "beamer slide"

[image]

using the essentially the code:

```
  \begin{AnnotatedImage}[width=0.8]{abacus.pdf}
    \draw[red, rounded corners, thick](0.2,0.85) rectangle(0.5,0.71);
    \draw[<-,red](0.2,0.78)--++(-0.1,0);
  \end{AnnotatedImage};
```

[This MWE will not compile as I used a random PDF file `abacus.pdf` on my computer and you won't have this...unfortunately, nice packages like [mwe](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe) don't supply PDF files.] The optional argument to the environment allows you set the mage dimensions and inside the environment you can use arbitrary [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) commands. In addition, there is also a `\annotate` command. See [Image with some overlaid text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398584/image-with-some-overlaid-text) for more details.

For a multi-page PDF file this almost certainly won't work but it will work if you extract the pages that you want to annotate. The other option would be to be use [pdfpages](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) to extract only the pages that you need. If you need this let me know as it shouldn't be hard to modify my code to use [pdfpages](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) directly.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\tikzset{% styling for the overlay
  annotatedImage/x/.initial = 0.7,% default overlay position
  annotatedImage/y/.initial = 0.7,
  annotatedImage/width/.initial = 1,% default image width
  annotatedImage/.unknown/.code = {% unknown keys are appended to style
    % to append to a style we need to expand everything first
    \edef\tikzappend{\noexpand\tikzset{annotatedImage/.append style =
                {\pgfkeyscurrentname=\pgfkeyscurrentvalue}}}
    \tikzappend
  },
  annotatedImage/.style = {% default overlay style
    draw=red, ultra thick, rounded corners, rectangle,
  }
}

\newsavebox\annotatedImageBox% need to calculate the width and height

% internal helper functions
\newcommand\AnnotatedImageVal[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/annotatedImage/#1}}
\newcommand\SetUpAnnotatedImage[2]{% set keys and dimensions to scale image
    \tikzset{annotatedImage/.cd, #1}%
    \sbox\annotatedImageBox{\includegraphics[width=\AnnotatedImageVal{width}\textwidth,
                                          keepaspectratio]{#2}}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\annotatedHeight{\ht\annotatedImageBox/28.453}% convert from px to a tikz length
    \pgfmathsetmacro\annotatedWidth{\wd\annotatedImageBox/28.453}%
}

% usage: \annotatedImage[node options]{image}{text}
\NewDocumentCommand\annotatedImage{ O{} m m}{%
  \bgroup% start a group to keep tikz changes local
    \SetUpAnnotatedImage{#1}{#2}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=\annotatedWidth, yscale=\annotatedHeight]%
        \node[inner sep=0, anchor=south west] (image) at (0,0) {\usebox{\annotatedImageBox}};
        \node[annotatedImage] at (\AnnotatedImageVal{x},\AnnotatedImageVal{y}) {#3};
    \end{tikzpicture}%y
  \egroup%
}

% usage: \annotate <insert favourite node commands>;
\newcommand\annotate[1][]{\node[annotatedImage,#1]}

% usage: \begin{AnnotatedImage][width(default 1)]{image} tikz commands....\end{AnnotatedImage}
\newenvironment{AnnotatedImage}[2][1]{%
  \SetUpAnnotatedImage{#1}{#2}%
  \tikzpicture[xscale=\annotatedWidth, yscale=\annotatedHeight]
    \node[inner sep=0, anchor=south west] at (0,0) {\usebox{\annotatedImageBox}};
}{\endtikzpicture}


\begin{document}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}{PDF example}

  \begin{AnnotatedImage}[width=0.8]{abacus.pdf}
    \draw[red, rounded corners, thick](0.2,0.85) rectangle(0.5,0.71);
    \draw[<-,red](0.2,0.78)--++(-0.1,0);
  \end{AnnotatedImage};

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much, Andrew! ... here is a link to the pdf I want to include: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262938427_Kalman_Filter_With_Recursive_Covariance_Estimation-Sequentially_Estimating_Process_Noise_Covariance   ... so. I want to include only the second page, and only points 3) to 5). I want to mark the first two lines, as well as the complete paragraph 5). ... I have just realized: In pdf24-Creator, when isolating a single page from a pdf, it becomes either a jpg or a png. ... does this render things a little easier?

Comment: My code works equally well with jpg, png, pdf, ... If you only want (part of) one page then I recommend extracting it and using the code above.

Comment: ok. Thx, again!