# add legend in graphic in PNG format

Tags: graphics, captions, png

I have the following chart in a png format that I need to include in latex file:

[image]

There is a way to add a legend over the figure using latex, like in the outline below?

[image]

Edit: Simple working code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{tek00000.png}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than posting images it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. People are normally happy to help provided that you give them something to start from.

Comment: One way to do this is to use my answer to the post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398584/image-with-some-overlaid-text